# Where is iPhone crash report UUID recorded?

Tags: iphone, crash

Sometimes I am unable to symbolicate my application's stack frames in a crash report. This is because I do not have an older .app and .dSYM. I was trying to force XCode to use my newer .app and .dSYM as the app has not changed significantly. Is there a way to modify the UUID associated with the crash report?

Is the UUID stored in file's metadata instead of in the file itself? Is there a way to change it to achieve what I am trying to do?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The UUID is never stored with the crash report. There are identifiers in the first few lines, but none of them is the UUID.

Also you can't re-symbolicating with dSYM of another build. Even if you don't change the app, the symbols in the new build can change.

Comment: Even a slight change in your compiled application can lead to totally different memory addresses for everything.